# Passing value to a function with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I use knockout here on a very basic example where **I would like to pass the value of the clicked item to the function**. I tried something which doesn't work. Does someone can show me how to proceed? Maybe I'm doint the wrong way?

Thanks for your help.

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <h2 data-bind="value: 'A', click: myFunction">Aaaaa</h2>  
    <h2 data-bind="value: 'B', click: myFunction">Bbbbb</h2>
    <h2 data-bind="value: 'C', click: myFunction">Ccccc</h2>
</div>

// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {

    this.myFunction = function (elm)
    {
        alert('you clicked: ' + elm);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/10229/

PS: I know we can do `...click: function () { myFunction('A'); }">` but I think there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value from event target (which is `h2` element):

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {

    this.myFunction = function (data, event)
    {
        debugger;
        alert('you clicked: ' + event.target.value);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Read more on [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
this.myFunction = function (vm, event)
    {
        alert('you clicked: ' + event.srcElement);
    }
```

Comment: Some more elaboration wouldn't hurt I think :)

Comment: I agree. although the 2nd parameter (`event`) is a bit self-explaining and the OP can realize that it's what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.myFunction = function (val1, val2)
{
    ...;
}
```

and in binding you must to set:

```
<h2 data-bind="value: 'C', click: myFunction.bind($data, 'A', 'B')">Ccccc</h2>
```

This must help you. You can pass any count of values by this method.